# How do you find out the how many bytes are used for a certain data type in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to find out what how many bytes a data type holds in c++, but I am not sure where to start. I searched on google but could not find anything.

Comment: Doesn't `sizeof (type)` do what you want?

Comment: Do you want to include indirect storage usage? (Dynamically allocated space, like vectors and strings require.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc

Comment: Ouch, you guys are brutal. He was last seen 7 days after posting this question.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how you happen to miss out on [`sizeof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).

In the programming languages C and C++, the unary operator sizeof is used to calculate the size of any datatype.
The sizeof operator yields the size of its operand with respect to the size of type char.

```
sizeof ( type-name )
```

Refer to know more here : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Following is the example from MSDN :

```
size_t getPtrSize( char *ptr )
{
   return sizeof( ptr );
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char szHello[] = "Hello, world!";

   cout  << "The size of a char is: "
         << sizeof( char )
         << "\nThe length of " << szHello << " is: "
         << sizeof szHello
         << "\nThe size of the pointer is "
         << getPtrSize( szHello ) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sizeof operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "bool:\t\t" << sizeof(bool) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "char:\t\t" << sizeof(char) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "wchar_t:\t" << sizeof(wchar_t) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "short:\t\t" << sizeof(short) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "int:\t\t" << sizeof(int) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "long:\t\t" << sizeof(long) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "float:\t\t" << sizeof(float) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "double:\t\t" << sizeof(double) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "long double:\t" << sizeof(long double) << " bytes" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bool:       1 bytes
char:       1 bytes
wchar_t:    2 bytes
short:      2 bytes
int:        4 bytes
long:       4 bytes
float:      4 bytes
double:     8 bytes
long double:    12 bytes
```

Used MinGW g++ 4.7.2 Windows